# winforms, loop through components

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to loop through components on a form, but components seems to be null.
So, how do I loop through components (NOT CONTROLS) on a form ?

```
public partial class FormBase : Form
{
    public FormBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FixVisualDesignerIssues();
    }

    protected void FixVisualDesignerIssues()
    {
        // this.components is always NULL ????????
        foreach (var comp in this.components.Components.OfType<BindingSource>())
        {
            ((BindingSource)comp).do something, whatever
        }
    }
```

EDITED as requested

```
 public partial class FormBaseList : Test_app.FormBase
{
    public FormBaseList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


public partial class FormBaseDetail : Test_app.FormBase
{
    public FormBaseDetail():base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gttDataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration and initialization of the element _gttDataTable_?

Comment: `this.components` wouldn't compile without declaration. So check your code or paste the way you are setting this instnace.

Comment: I edited the code so it uses a bindingsource, so people will stop asking about the declaration of the component I was searching for. It does not matter what the declaration is, what matters is that this.components is null. Please read the question before answering

Comment: this.components compiles just fine

Comment: this.components is a property of the Form class in winforms, it is not something I wrote but microsoft wrote it. I just want to know how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating the `BindingSource` the following way, only then it will be contained in the components container.

```
BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource(components);
```

If you are using any other way to create the binding source, there will be nothing in the `components` container.

Comment: the bindingsource is created by dropping it on a form in the designer. So I would have to check the designer.cs to see how its been created ?

Comment: This is a problem, I have a base form where other forms inherit from. On the base form there are no components but I wanted to use the baseform to loop through all components that where put on it by inherited forms. Since the inherited form will eventually also call InitialiseComponents it should be able to find all components at that time ? This is how I did this in Delphi, how can this be done in c# ?

Comment: Can you please share the code which shows form structure? Note that component collection and bindingsource are both private objects.

Comment: Well, the entire code of the baseform is in the question, there is nothing more in there. All other forms inherit from this one and using the visual designer components like bindingsource and controls like textboxes and datagridviews where put on them.

Comment: You cannot access the inherited form's components from base form.

Comment: Let me get this right, when I put a component on FormBaseList that inherits from FormBase than in a method defined on FormBase it is not possible at runtime to loop through all components and find components put there by FormBaseList, even if FormBaseList ia the caller of the method ?

Comment: When the constructor of FormBaseList is called, it will call the method FixDesignerIssues defined on FormBase, right ? At this time should FixDesignerIssues than not be able to find all components from FormBaseList ?

Comment: Yes but your components are not part of component collection in base form. components object on base form and in child form are 2 different objects.

Comment: Does FormBaseList not uses its own components than when calling this method ? I am trying to understand c# oop implementation, I am used to Delphi where components would contain all components from the creating class and classes it inherited from

Comment: I looked at the code in Designer.cs of the forms, it seems that each of these forms is indeed  creating its own instance of components in stead of using the instance of its parent class. Looks like a oop design flaw to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67894/discussion-between-danish-and-guidog).